# Spring Join Single Column of a Composite Key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, composite

The Console Error: A Foreign key refering com.api.subscriber.pojo.MapperSubscriberTracker from com.api.tracker.pojo.Tracker has the wrong number of column. should be 2

```
public class MapperSubscriberTracker implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "tracker_id")
    private int trackerID;

    @ManyToOne
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "subscriber_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Subscriber subscriber;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "mapperSubscriberTracker", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Tracker> trackers;
    ...
}



public class Tracker {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "subscriber_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private MapperSubscriberTracker mapperSubscriberTracker;

    ...
}
```

I've also tried the following method with the same error:

```
B {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b3", referencedColumnName = "a3")
    privte A a;

}

A {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "a3", referencedColumnName = "b3")
    privte List<B> bList;

}
```

I understand it wants 2 keys to join on because of the composite key but I don't want to do that. Is there a way to force it to join on the one column?

Comment: It has the number of FK columns for a reason (why don't you actually show the `@Id` fields?!).

Comment: I added the IDs. I understand why you would normally want to use the FK, in this case I just want to join based off of one column though.

Comment: You identify the "owner" of a Tracker using both fields (columns). If only 1 is really adequate then you should fix your model to do just that.

Comment: Is there no way to do it then? I could add an id column and make the 2 unique but I'd never even need that id column (since this is just doing a mapping). And I guess that's what you are referring to as "fix the model" (which I'd argue, just more noise).   The water down version of why I need to do a 1 column join is because some Tracker entries are shared.

Comment: JPA models object relationships, and your object relationships says that "we identify the owner of a Tracker using 2 fields (columns)". Consequently NO, you cannot do that, since it makes no sense in the context of an object relationship. If you had a simple (single) id column for MapperSubscriberTracker then it would just use that. If a Tracker is owned by multiple MapperSubscriberTracker then you should use a join table relation